# How to send nested json object to mvc controller using ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application. I have the following view model in c#:

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class PersonModel
{
    public ContactModel Contact;

    public PersonModel()
    {
        Contact = new ContactModel();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
}
```

Now i have the same json model at client side which i want to post to server. I am using following jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "address to controller",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function () {
        alert("data saved successfully");
    }
});
```

But only PersonModel properties are get mapped but Contact properties are null. Can anybody please tell me what i am missing??

Comment: What's the content of `data`?

Comment: The content of data variable is `"{"Contact":{"Address":"xyz","City":"xyz","State":"xyz"},"FirstName":"xyz","LastName":"xyz","Profession":"87"}"`

Comment: I figured out the problem, the issue was that i did not give the set; access to the property `Contact` in my `PersonModel` so default model binder was unable to set the new object to `Contact` property. I just added `{ get; set; }` for `Contact` property and problem solved!

Answer (score 6):

You need for format your string to proper json -

Say if you model is -

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class PersonModel
{
    public ContactModel Contact { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
}
```

Then you AJAX Post should be like this -

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#click1').click(function (e) {

            var studentData = {
                "FirstName": "Rami",
                "LastName": "Vemula" ,
                "Contact": { "City": "Hyd"}
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Submit")",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(studentData),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
            },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Then output is going to be -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a instance of ContactModel and assign it to contact under PersonModel after creating instance of PersonModel. 
Please let me know in case of any clarification needed

Comment: I dont understand your suggestion please clarify ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@html` helper for properties then `form.serialize()` method will bind all the properties otherwise if you are using html elements like `<input>` the assign their name property same as model property.

```
<input type="text" name="Contact.FirstName" value="@Model.Contact.FirstName"/>
```