# Assigning Javascript value to Model variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass large number of data from javascript to model. I already tried it by first sending it to data but its not working with large data so is there any way to set model value from javascript

What I am currently doing is

```
function SaveData() {

        var BatchNo = new Array();

        $("table#tbl1 tr").each(function (row, tr) {

            BatchNo[row]  = $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()

        });
        BatchNo.shift();

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SaveMedicineTable", "MedicinePurchase")",
            traditional : true,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                BatchNo: BatchNo,

            },
            success: function (result) {

                //Your success message
            },
            error: function (result) {
                //alert("Error" + result);
                //Your error message
            }
        });
    }
```

This function on save button click will call a controller but however my data is huge so i cant get to it. So I need something different from which i can set model value or pass huge data
Below is my controller code. This many feilds I am passing from javascript to controller

```
Function SaveMedicineTable(MedicineName() As String, BatchNo() As String, ExpiryDate() As String, Qty() As String, FreeQty() As String, PurRate() As String,
                               Mrp() As String, SellRate() As String, Unit() As String, Amount() As String, DiscPer() As String, DiscAmt() As String,
                               GrossAmt() As String, VatPer() As String, VatAmt() As String, AddVatPer() As String, AddVatAmt() As String, NetAmt() As String, MedicineID() As String,
                              SupplierID As String, ChallanNo As String, PurchaseDate As String, BillNo As String, BillDate As String, PayDate As String,
                              PayMode As String, ItemTotal As String, BankName As String, DocNo As String, AddLessAmt As String, AddLessRemarks As String, BillAmount As String,
                        BillRemarks As String, AcDate As String, chkEdit As String) As JsonResult
        Dim mpm As New MedicinePurchase
        mpm.HospitalID = Session("hospital_id")
        mpm.WorkingYear = 2014
        mpm.PurchaseType = 1
        mpm.SupplierID = SupplierID
        mpm.ChallanNo = ChallanNo
        mpm.PurchaseDate = PurchaseDate
        mpm.BillNo = BillNo
        mpm.BillDate = BillDate
        mpm.PayDate = PayDate
        mpm.PayMode = PayMode
        mpm.ItemTotal = ItemTotal
        mpm.BankName = BankName
        mpm.DocNo = DocNo
        mpm.AddLessAmt = AddLessAmt
        mpm.AddLessRemarks = AddLessRemarks
        mpm.BillAmount = BillAmount
        mpm.BillRemarks = BillRemarks
        mpm.AcDate = AcDate
        mpm.ChkEdit = chkEdit
        mpm.AddMedicinePurchase(MedicineName, BatchNo, ExpiryDate, Qty, FreeQty, PurRate,
                                    Mrp, SellRate, Unit, Amount, DiscPer, DiscAmt,
                                    GrossAmt, VatPer, VatAmt, AddVatPer, AddVatAmt, NetAmt, MedicineID)

        Return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Function
```

This is the another error I got

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found): http://localhost:54248/MedicinePurchase/SaveMedicineTable?{%22BatchNo%22:[%22167%22,%224623005%22,%22P1210022%22,%220021%22,%22ra9002%22,%220911055%22,%221011248%22,%22B1005%22,%22247%22,%22522005%22,%22296020%22,%22T-70020%22,%221836%22,%22113%22,%22D201C133%22,%22904672%22,%2210A2911%22,%22AD82695%22,%22LBB40019%22,%22a90149%22,%2210B1512%22,%222530%22,%22LW152036AS0%22,%22DE61206%22,%22H009%22,%22E005%22,%22727%22,%221572%22,%22ZC261003%22,%221713137%22,%22AP012%22,%22A81307%22,%22D90118%22,%22FD6L12L%22,%22282404%22,%22NL102%22,%226064011%22,%22BA11%22,%22ANT101%22,%22BK49%22,%22C00805%22,%22F40002%22,%227054046%22,%227024025%22,%227014029%22,%2247612%22,%224785001%22,%224804002%22,%22A402%22,%22BAE29%22,%22ROE405%22,%22S026%22,%22E048%22,%22ELE402%22,%22R005%22,%22FZD412%22,%22C006%22,%22B004%22],%22ExpiryDate%22:[%2230/11/2016%22,%2231/10/2015%22,%2230/09/2014%22,%2231/12/2009%22,%2230/06/2010%22,%2230/10/2014%22,%2231/10/2015%22,%2230/06/2016%22,%2231/12/2007%22,%2231/10/2007%22,%2230/11/2010%22,%2231/07/2008%22,%2231/08/2009%22,%2228/02/2007%22,%2231/08/2015%22,%2231/03/2013%22,%2231/12/2014%22,%2230/11/2011%22,%2231/12/2016%22,%2230/12/2011%22,%2230/12/2014%22,%2231/05/2013%22,%2231/10/2015%22,%2230/06/2008%22,%2230/11/2010%22,%2230/11/2005%22,%2231/03/2009%22,%2230/09/2009%22,%2231/01/2008%22,%2230/05/2013%22,%2230/11/2014%22,%2230/11/2010%22,%2230/12/2010%22,%2231/08/2009%22,%2230/11/2006%22,%2231/01/2010%22,%2231/07/2006%22,%2231/08/2007%22,%2228/02/2007%22,%2231/12/2006%22,%2230/06/2006%22,%2231/12/2007%22,%2230/11/2007%22,%2230/11/2007%22,%2230/11/2007%22,%2230/11/2007%22,%2231/01/2008%22,%2230/11/2007%22,%2231/08/2007%22,%2231/01/2007%22,%2230/11/2006%22,%2231/08/2006%22,%2231/10/2006%22,%2230/09/2006%22,%2230/11/2006%22,%2231/10/2006%22,%2230/09/2006%22,%2231/12/2007%22],%22Qty%22:[%2211%22,%22100%22,%2220%22,%2210%22,%22120%22,%222400%22,%221200%22,%2212%22,%22120%22,%22300%22,%22100%22,%224%22,%22220%22,%2250%22,%2230%22,%222%22,%223600%22,%22100%22,%22120%22,%223%22,%226000%22,%221%22,%22500%22,%221%22,%22200%22,%225%22,%2250%22,%22100%22,%2250%22,%2210%22,%22100%22,%223%22,%22100%22,%2250%22,%2210%22,%22250%22,%2230%22,%223%22,%2250%22,%2250%22,%222%22,%2210%22,%2230%22,%2250%22,%2250%22,%2230%22,%2230%22,%2230%22,%222%22,%2250%22,%225%22,%2210%22,%222%22,%223%22,%225%22,%2220%22,%225%22,%225%22],%22FreeQty%22:[%220%22,%220%22,%226%22,%223%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%2230%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%2220%22,%222%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%2210%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22],%22PurRate%22:[%2269.57%22,%227.47%22,%2234.51%22,%2240.39%22,%224.93%22,%223.55%22,%223.55%22,%22100%22,%220.84%22,%221.02%22,%226.76%22,%22138.04%22,%223.23%22,%223.57%22,%2211.01%22,%22150%22,%221.85%22,%223.71%22,%224.8%22,%2212.75%22,%221.7%22,%2211%22,%225.33%22,%22158.39%22,%220.74%22,%229.68%22,%221.75%22,%2223.21%22,%224.79%22,%2218%22,%228.3%22,%2226.85%22,%221.14%22,%229.48%22,%2210.54%22,%220.41%22,%226.96%22,%2224.16%22,%223.42%22,%223.12%22,%2238.64%22,%2221.99%22,%222.02%22,%223.74%22,%226.29%22,%222.93%22,%222.14%22,%220.91%22,%2274.34%22,%225.19%22,%2230.4%22,%2229.38%22,%2262.71%22,%22104.22%22,%2220.76%22,%2224.09%22,%2254.09%22,%2238.55%22],%22Mrp%22:[%22100%22,%2210.5%22,%2244.85%22,%2251.75%22,%226.17%22,%2212.25%22,%2212.25%22,%22135%22,%220.95%22,%221.25%22,%228.45%22,%22170%22,%224.24%22,%224.05%22,%2213.51%22,%22210%22,%228.25%22,%224.8%22,%226.3%22,%2215.86%22,%226.9%22,%2213.85%22,%226.8%22,%22209%22,%220.95%22,%2211%22,%222%22,%2230.46%22,%225.76%22,%2225.7%22,%2252.5%22,%2235%22,%221.5%22,%2211.25%22,%2211.7%22,%220.5%22,%228%22,%2227.5%22,%223.9%22,%223.54%22,%2243.86%22,%2225%22,%222.36%22,%224.27%22,%227.3%22,%223.33%22,%222.38%22,%221.08%22,%2286%22,%225.9%22,%2235%22,%2231.9%22,%2269.05%22,%22115%22,%2222.82%22,%2228%22,%2262.5%22,%2245%22],%22SellRate%22:[%22100%22,%2210.5%22,%2244.85%22,%2251.75%22,%226.17%22,%2212.25%22,%2212.25%22,%22135%22,%220.988%22,%221.3%22,%228.787999999999998%22,%22176.8%22,%224.24%22,%224.212%22,%2213.51%22,%22210%22,%228.25%22,%224.8%22,%226.3%22,%2215.86%22,%226.9%22,%2213.85%22,%226.8%22,%22217.36%22,%220.95%22,%2211.44%22,%222.08%22,%2230.46%22,%225.9904%22,%2225.7%22,%2252.5%22,%2235%22,%221.5%22,%2211.7%22,%2212.168%22,%220.52%22,%228.32%22,%2228.6%22,%224.056%22,%223.6816%22,%2245.614399999999996%22,%2226%22,%222.4543999999999997%22,%224.440799999999999%22,%227.592%22,%223.4632%22,%222.4752%22,%221.1232%22,%2289.44%22,%226.136%22,%2236.4%22,%2233.176%22,%2271.812%22,%22119.6%22,%2223.7328%22,%2229.12%22,%2265%22,%2246.8%22],%22Unit%22:[%22FACE%20WASH%22,%22CAP%22,%22INJ%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Tab%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22TAB%22,%22Tab%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Tab%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Tab%22,%22Tab%22,%22Tab%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22,%22Pcs%22],%22Amount%22:[%22765.27%22,%22747%22,%22690.2%22,%22403.9%22,%22591.6%22,%228520%22,%224260%22,%221200%22,%22100.8%22,%22306%22,%22676%22,%22552.16%22,%22710.6%22,%22178.5%22,%22330.3%22,%22300%22,%226660%22,%22371%22,%22576%22,%2238.25%22,%2210200%22,%2211%22,%222665%22,%22158.39%22,%22148%22,%2248.4%22,%2287.5%22,%222321%22,%22239.5%22,%22180%22,%22830%22,%2280.55%22,%22114%22,%22474%22,%22105.4%22,%22102.5%22,%22208.8%22,%2272.48%22,%22171%22,%22156%22,%2277.28%22,%22219.9%22,%2260.6%22,%22187%22,%22314.5%22,%2287.9%22,%2264.2%22,%2227.3%22,%22148.68%22,%22259.5%22,%22152%22,%22293.8%22,%22125.42%22,%22312.66%22,%22103.8%22,%22481.8%22,%22270.45%22,%22192.75%22],%22DiscPer%22:[%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22],%22DiscAmt%22:[%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22],%22GrossAmt%22:[%22765.27%22,%22747%22,%22690.2%22,%22403.9%22,%22591.6%22,%228520%22,%224260%22,%221200%22,%22100.8%22,%22306%22,%22676%22,%22552.16%22,%22710.6%22,%22178.5%22,%22330.3%22,%22300%22,%226660%22,%22371%22,%22576%22,%2238.25%22,%2210200%22,%2211%22,%222665%22,%22158.39%22,%22148%22,%2248.4%22,%2287.5%22,%222321%22,%22239.5%22,%22180%22,%22830%22,%2280.55%22,%22114%22,%22474%22,%22105.4%22,%22102.5%22,%22208.8%22,%2272.48%22,%22171%22,%22156%22,%2277.28%22,%22219.9%22,%2260.6%22,%22187%22,%22314.5%22,%2287.9%22,%2264.2%22,%2227.3%22,%22148.68%22,%22259.5%22,%22152%22,%22293.8%22,%22125.42%22,%22312.66%22,%22103.8%22,%22481.8%22,%22270.45%22,%22192.75%22],%22VatPer%22:[%2212.5%22,%2212.5%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%220%22,%220%22,%224%22,%2212.5%22,%224%22,%220%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%2212.5%22,%224%22,%220%22,%220%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%224%22,%220%22,%224%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22],%22VatAmt%22:[%2295.66%22,%2293.38%22,%2227.61%22,%2216.156%22,%2223.664%22,%22340.8%22,%22170.4%22,%2248%22,%220%22,%2212.24%22,%2227.04%22,%2269.02%22,%2228.424%22,%220%22,%2213.21%22,%2212%22,%22266.4%22,%2214.84%22,%2223.04%22,%221.53%22,%22408%22,%220.44%22,%22106.6%22,%2219.799%22,%225.92%22,%220%22,%220%22,%2292.84%22,%229.58%22,%227.2%22,%2233.2%22,%223.222%22,%224.56%22,%2218.96%22,%220%22,%224.1%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22],%22AddVatPer%22:[%222.5%22,%222.5%22,%221%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%221%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%221%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%221%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22],%22AddVatAmt%22:[%2219.13%22,%2218.68%22,%226.9%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%223.3%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%225.76%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%2226.65%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22],%22NetAmt%22:[%22880.06%22,%22859.06%22,%22724.71%22,%22420.056%22,%22615.264%22,%228860.8%22,%224430.4%22,%221248%22,%22100.8%22,%22318.24%22,%22703.04%22,%22621.18%22,%22739.024%22,%22178.5%22,%22346.81%22,%22312%22,%226926.4%22,%22385.84%22,%22604.8%22,%2239.78%22,%2210608%22,%2211.44%22,%222798.25%22,%22178.189%22,%22153.92%22,%2248.4%22,%2287.5%22,%222413.84%22,%22249.08%22,%22187.2%22,%22863.2%22,%2283.77199999999999%22,%22118.56%22,%22492.96%22,%22105.4%22,%22106.6%22,%22208.8%22,%2272.48%22,%22171%22,%22156%22,%2277.28%22,%22219.9%22,%2260.6%22,%22187%22,%22314.5%22,%2287.9%22,%2264.2%22,%2227.3%22,%22148.68%22,%22259.5%22,%22152%22,%22293.8%22,%22125.42%22,%22312.66%22,%22103.8%22,%22481.8%22,%22270.45%22,%22192.75%22],%22MedicineID%22:[%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22,%22%22],%22SupplierID%22:%22%22,%22ChallanNo%22:%2211012%22,%22PurchaseDate%22:%2201/04/2014%22,%22BillNo%22:%2211012%22,%22BillDate%22:%2201/04/2014%22,%22PayDate%22:%2214/05/2014%22,%22PayMode%22:%22Cheque%22,%22ItemTotal%22:%222343.92%22,%22BankName%22:%22BOB%22,%22DocNo%22:%22521669%22,%22AddLessAmt%22:%220.08%22,%22AddLessRemarks%22:%22%22,%22BillAmount%22:%222344%22,%22BillRemarks%22:%22%22,%22AcDate%22:%22%22,%22chkEdit%22:%22Yes%22}
```

Comment: why its not working? any transport errors?

Comment: `Assigning Javascript value to Model variable` - Simple answer: You Can't. ASP.Net MVC is server side technology, JS is client side. You  have to POST/GET data from client side to server side either by regular POST/GET or through AJAX.

Comment: Actually this is not a actual scenario I am passing 18 array and 20 other variables

Comment: Ok @ramiramilu but is there a way I can pass it to even controller or set value of controller

Comment: If you are using `AJAX POST` in `JSON` format, you should be able to pass data.

Comment: Give me a sample `JSON` formatted data, I will create simple POC for you.

Comment: Show the controller method your posting to. Unless your table has millions of row, I doubt size is the issue

Comment: I have added my controller code

Comment: In javascript on error it showing me object[Object]

Comment: I have put break on the function I am calling its actually noy even going to the function. WHen I do this thing for 4 to 5 value in each array it works perfectly

Comment: @ramiramilu I dont knw how to give you a sample JSON formatted data

Comment: Why are you taking those number of parameters as arguments, instead you can take `MedicinePurchase` as one argument. You can find how to `POST` and `JSON.Stringify` from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550745/how-to-send-nested-json-object-to-mvc-controller-using-ajax

Comment: How will I catch array there

Comment: I tried JsonStringify but it dont work still getting same error in java console

Comment: @ramiramilu please check the edit i got this thing too

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this answer will help you. Using ajax post and object method you can pass large values to model. In the example I have passed 10 values. 5 string array and 5 string variables

**JQuery AJAX**

```
function SaveDetails() {
    var obj = {
        arr1: ["1", "1", "1"],
        arr2: ["2", "2", "2"],
        arr3: ["3", "3", "3"],
        arr4: ["4", "4", "4"],
        arr5: ["5", "5", "5"],
        str1: "String 1",
        str2: "String 2",
        str3: "String 3",
        str4: "String 4",
        str5: "String 5"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/SaveTable',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        cache: false,
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public void SaveTable(List<String> arr1, List<String> arr2, List<String> arr3, List<String> arr5, string str1, string str2, string str3, string str4, string str5)
    {
      // Do your code
    }
```

Comment: I have already used but its not working dude same error Error 414: uri is too long

Comment: @Snehal, hi have you tried POST method?. check this link this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23237608/2501044