# how to assign values to nested object through json object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, nested

This is my model class:

```
public class SearchForFlight
{
    public SearchForFlight()
    {
        Segments = new otherType();
    }
    public int AdultCount { get; set; }
    public JourneyType JourneyType { get; set; }
    public string Sources { get; set; }

    public otherType Segments { get; set; }
}
public class otherType
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public FlightCabinClass FlightCabinClass { get; set;}
    public DateTime PreferredDepartureTime { get; set;
    public DateTime PreferredArrivalTime { get; set; }
}
```

Now, My requirement is to post objects along with nested object to an external api.
The required form is something like this:

```
{
   AdultCount: $("#AdultCount").val(),
   JourneyType: $("#JourneyType :selected").text(),
   PreferredAirlines: null,
   Segments: [
              {
               Origin: $("#Origin").val(),
               Destination: $("#Destination").val(),
               FlightCabinClass: $("#FlightCabinClass").val(),
               PreferredDepartureTime:$("#PreferredDepartureTime").val(),
               PreferredArrivalTime: $("#PreferredArrivalTime").val(),
              }
             ]
        }
```

So, i have created another class OtherType and put all those nested objects into it.
I got the idea from this so question
[How to send nested json object to mvc controller using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550745/how-to-send-nested-json-object-to-mvc-controller-using-ajax)
Now, this is my Script tag with all the code inside to post simple objects along with nested objects.But nested objects value comes out to be null.
How should i model this code here.

```
  <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {                 
                    $("#btnPost").click(function () {
                        var sof = {
                            AdultCount: $("#AdultCount").val(),
                            JourneyType: $("#JourneyType :selected").text(),
                            PreferredAirlines: null,
                                Segments: [
                                {
                                    Origin: $("#Origin").val(),
                                    Destination: $("#Destination").val(),
                                    FlightCabinClass: $("#FlightCabinClass").val(),
                                    PreferredDepartureTime: $("#PreferredDepartureTime").val(),
                                    PreferredArrivalTime: $("#PreferredArrivalTime").val(),
                                }
                            ],
                        };

                        $.ajax(
                            {
                                url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
                                type: "Post",
                                data: sof,
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert(data);
                                }
                            });        
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

Posted Properties values for Origin, Destination comes out to be null.

The textbox rendered on view page are something like this:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Segments.Origin)
```

Any hint please.

Comment: what is your FlightCabinClass model ?

Comment: `Segments` is an object, not a collection so you cannot create an array. Just use `data: $('form.Serialize(),` to serialize all values of all form controls, or if you do want to write all this manually, then use `Segments.Origin = $("#Segments_Origin").val(),` etc (and note that your element will have `id="Segments_Origin"`, not `id="Origin"`)

Comment: YUPP u r right i have changed those id values already but i have to post all these values to certain air portal rest api so i was trying to post data as given in documentation of api otherwise it replies Bad Request @StephenMuecke

Comment: using `$('form').serialize()` will correctly serialize all your form controls assuming you have generated you view correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the array [] for Segments. Use contentType and stringify in your $.ajax func. Use the generated id for the Origin. It might not be "Origin". So,pls change it accordingly.

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {                 
                $("#btnPost").click(function () {
                    var sof = {
                        AdultCount: $("#AdultCount").val(),
                        JourneyType: $("#JourneyType :selected").text(),
                        PreferredAirlines: null,
                        Segments: {
                                Origin: $("#Origin").val(),
                                Destination: $("#Destination").val(),
                                FlightCabinClass: $("#FlightCabinClass").val(),
                                PreferredDepartureTime: $("#PreferredDepartureTime").val(),
                                PreferredArrivalTime: $("#PreferredArrivalTime").val(),
                            },
                    };

                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
                            type: "Post",
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            data: JSON.stringify(sof),
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        });        
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: for the good sake, at last api returned 200 status code. i was just strict about to give rest api data in format mentioned in document however ur suggesstion worked @Karthik M R

Comment: If you are using nested objects, the best practise is to use JSON.stringify function and mention application/json. If you don't use JSON.stringify then, the default behaviour of jquery is to send the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded